# datetimepicker in vb.net

Tags: datetime

i am using the following statement:
dim d as date
d=format(datetimepicker1.value.date,"dd/MM/yyyy")
but when the application is executed,following error is returned:
not a valid month..
why is it so??
please help..

Answer (score 0):

Value itself is DateTime object and hence formatting is not required. And from datetime, 
pick date ->
  d = datetimepicker1.value.date